# Back Button gets hidden in choose StartMenu Page for NSIS - Ultra Modern UI

Tags: nsis

I have pages lined up like this:

```
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE PageCheck ;Hiding Welcome Page if needed

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME

Page custom ChooseDirAndOverWrite ChooseDirAndOverWriteLeave

!define MUI_STARTMENUPAGE_NODISABLE

!define MUI_STARTMENUPAGE_DEFAULTFOLDER $StartMenuDefault

!insertmacro UMUI_PAGE_ALTERNATIVESTARTMENU "Application" $StartMenuFolder

!insertmacro UMUI_PAGE_CONFIRM
```

When I reach the screen "choose Startmenu folder", which is `!insertmacro UMUI_PAGE_ALTERNATIVESTARTMENU "Application" $StartMenuFolder`, the Back button is visible for a split second and then gets hidden, only on first time.
On clicking next, then coming back, the Button is enabled there onwards.

What may be causing this behaviour, and where can I get it corrected ?

Also, I read that Ultra Modern UI StartMenu Page does not have a Show Function. Is there a work around for it ?

Comment: Ultra Modern UI is old and deprecated, I am not sure whether someone can help you with this :(

Comment: ok, Could you please suggest any work around for this problem to create a choose start menu folder page.

Comment: I mean: this technology is old => there are no developers who use it. So probably no one can help you. Some NSIS gurus may fix this (Anders is the best!) but rather switch to nsDialogs or Graphical Installer which are preferred now.

Comment: Do you want the back button to always be visible or never?